# How to remove the background of a (regular) view (Android)

Tags: java, android, view, background

I have the following code:

```
View view = new View(this);  
view.setBackgroundDrawable(...);  
...
```

And here I want to remove that background.
Just turn it back as it was before.

I tried these and failed:

```
view.setBackgroundDrawable(null);  
view.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);  
view.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
```

Any more ideas?

Comment: Does calling `invalidate()` to force a redraw make a difference?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`view.setBackgroundDrawable(null);` should work.

You may try one of these:

```
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
//or
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000")); //whatever color
```

Make sure the view you're applying the background to is the correct instance.

Comment: Very minor update: `setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable d)` is deprecaded now. Use `setBackground(Drawable d)` instead.

Comment: if app/parent view is not white so when do with white we are changing the UI

Answer (score 0):

That's because `view.setBackgroundColor(int)` expects a color resource not an "actual" integer value. Try declaring it in your colors.xml, see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color). However, I'm not quite sure what you mean by "removing" the background. If you want it to have the original value, then I suggest you store the original drawable (using `getBackground()`) somewhere. Otherwise you will most likely lose formatting, since most default backgrounds in Android are Drawable resources (selectors), not simple colors.

Comment: `view.setBackgroundColor(int)` takes an ARGB color, not a resource.